# Marketing Cloud - How to group DE rows with repeated values

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have a DE (DataExtension) for members, and another for members' children, which are also members but linked to the parent in question.
[image: DataExtensions Example]

I would like to be able to group up sends, so I don't overburden the parent with, for example 3 emails if they register their 3 kids at the same time. Both DE's are linked by the parent's Id, the column used later for the send logic.

One of the options I though of is achieving something like this:
[image: New DE to Obtain]

I was thinking of using the `STUFF` function, but I don't see a way to make it work.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question to include samples of the source data and the desired output.  The "group up sends" isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

We are unable to completely understand your requirement!
Based on a similar project, I have tried to illustrate your requirement. Hope this helps you to implement. [If NOT at least it might help some others trying to implement similar one!.

- Hoping your NOT Triggering emails immediately after registration.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering, I will try this method and see if I can achieve what I was trying to :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote a **[blog post](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-sql-data-into-a-delimited-string/)** a while back about pretty much this exact thing. Reference here for a ton of more details on the whole process.

You were right to go with `Stuff`, but I think the part you were missing was the `FOR XML PATH` part.

Example of solution:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
emailStr = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT ',' + b.email
    FROM [myDE] b
    WHERE a.id = b.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')
FROM [myDE]
GROUP BY ID
```

In this case it takes the `email` field from myDE and makes it a delimited field that is grouped together by the `id` field.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! The issue I find with this solution is that I get an error saying `Unable to create temporary data extension: Field name cannot contain the character =.`

Comment: If its Query Studio then know that tosses syntax errors on things valid in an Auto Studio Query Activity